# Scientific value is displaying ,while export data from GridView in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

Scientific value is displaying ,while export data from GridView in MVC

Hello All,

I am trying to export data from a GridView in Excel in MVC .

It’s showing scientific value instead of real data as below

The data should be 5153E1, but after exporting  it’s showing it as 5.15E+04.

Please find the code as below:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("TEST");
        dt.Rows.Add("5153E1");

        var dataGrid = new GridView();
        dataGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dataGrid.DataBind();

        //Code to Export Data To Excel
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report_Excel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        dataGrid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();


        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Can you increase column width in excel? Just drag and drop. I used something like this and it all worked fine. It's just excel shows the values in this weird way when column width is not big enough.

Comment: It is the `E` in your string.. that is a standard numeric format for exponential